# Is it possible to create an inheritance like structure for strings files in Xcode?

Tags: ios, localizable.strings

I have an application that has different sets of strings based on the target. Is it possible to have one base strings file and then only override a few keys in another?

For example, if my base file is this:

```
"some-string" = "base-value"
"other-string" = "1234"
```

Then for one of my targets, associate another strings file that has the following:

```
"some-string" = "overridden-value"
```

So, if I run the target that contains the additional strings file, the output would be:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"some-string", nil) => "overridden value"
NSLocalizedString(@"other-string", nil) => "1234"
```

I would greatly prefer not to throw unmodified strings in the overriding strings file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"some-string",
                                  @"additionalStringsTableName", 
                                  [NSBundle mainBundle],
                                  NSLocalizedString(@"some-string", nil),
                                  nil);
```

Perform a lookup in your overriding strings file. If that fails, return the default `NSLocalizedString()` result.

It's a rather ugly thing to have all over your code. So you might want to work some macro magic to get a shorter call. Something like this:

```
#define MyLocalizedString(key, comment) NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(key,
                                  OVERRIDE_TABLE_NAME, 
                                  [NSBundle mainBundle],
                                  NSLocalizedString(key, comment),
                                  comment);
```

(written on multiple lines for clarity). Then you could define `OVERRIDE_TABLE_NAME` as a compiler option.

Comment: Hi Hal, thanks for the response. That's definitely an option, but I was hoping for a more simple built-in mechanism that would take care of that. The main problem with this method is that it requires the application to be aware of the additional strings files. Not a huge issue - it could be remedied with an argument containing the strings file name associated with the target.